# Not able to update Picker.SelectedIndex

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have an odd issue I can't explain the reason for it - maybe someone here can shed some light on it

I have a ticket scanning app in Xamarin Forms currently testing it on android
the interface allows you to:

1. type an order number and click the check order Button
2. use the camera scanner to scan which automatically triggers check order
3. use the barcode scanner to scan which automatically triggers check order

after the check order validation, user has to select the number of tickets from a drop down list and press confrim entry button

what I'm trying to do, is if the seats available on that ticket is just 1 - then automatically trigger confirm entry button functionality

problem that I have is that - some of my logic depends on setting the drop down index in code - for some reason it doesn't update - as seen in the debugger shot here

[image: value not updating]

and this is the second tme I've noticed this today, earlier it was a var I was trying to assign a string and it kept coming up as null - eventually I replaced that code

is this a bug in xamarin ?

code has been simplified:

```
async void OnCheckOrderButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ValidateOrderEntry();
}

private async void scanCameraButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    messageLabel.Text = string.Empty;
    var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
    options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
        ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_8, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
    };

    var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(options);
    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        //stop scan
        scanPage.IsScanning = false;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            //pop the page and get the result
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
            orderNoEntry.Text = result.Text;
            //automatically trigger update
            await ValidateOrderEntry();
        });

    };
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
}

private async Task ValidateOrderEntry()
{
   //...other code....

    checkInPicker.Items.Clear();                
    if (availablTickets == 1)
    {
        checkInPickerStack.IsVisible = true;
        checkInPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;

        messageLabel.Text = "Ticket OK! - " + orderNoEntry.Text;
        messageLabel.TextColor = Color.Green;
        //select the only element
        checkInPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
        await PostDoorEntry();
    }
   //...other code....
}

private async Task PostDoorEntry()
{
    int entryCount = checkInPicker.SelectedIndex + 1;
    //... more code...
    //...post api code..
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but you clear all the items a few lines above it, so there are no items in there and thus you can't set the selected index to anything other than -1?

Comment: actually - you are right ... it's getting populated in another case below this  - I moved it around and didn't realise it :-/ - thanks!

Comment: Upgraded it to an answer for you to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but you clear all the items a few lines above the one you are pointing out. That means there are no items in your `Picker` and thus you can't set the `SelectedIndex` to anything other than -1, simply because there are no items.